# Query deletion does not remove entries from association table

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I implemented an association table for a self-referential many-to-many relationship. Similar to as described in the [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many). However, when I delete all node objects using `session.query(Node).delete()`, the association table retains its entries.

**Reproducible example:**

```
a, b = Node(), Node()
a.children = [b]
session.add_all([a, b])
session.commit()
session.query(Node).delete()
session.commit()
assert(session.query(Node).count() == 0)
assert(session.query(link).count() == 0)
```

**Model:**

```
Base = declarative_base()    
link = Table('link', Base.metadata,
             Column('parent', Integer, ForeignKey('node.id')),
             Column('child', Integer, ForeignKey('node.id')))

class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship('Node',
                            secondary=link,
                            primaryjoin=id == link.c.parent,
                            secondaryjoin=id == link.c.child,
                            backref='parents')
```

The first assert passes, as intended. The second assert fails. (1 != 0)

If I replace the `session.query(Node).delete()` with either:

```
session.delete(a)
```

or

```
session.delete(b)
```

...then the assert passes, as intended.

**What is the correct way of deleting all objects from the `Node` table to ensure corresponding entries in the `link` table get deleted?**

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#deleting-rows-from-the-many-to-many-table) on deleting from M2M association tables may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete) about `Query.delete()`:

> The method does not offer in-Python cascading of relationships - it is
>   assumed that ON DELETE CASCADE/SET NULL/etc. is configured for any
>   foreign key references which require it, otherwise the database may
>   emit an integrity violation if foreign key references are being
>   enforced.

I ended up just writing the deletion as follows:

```
for node in session.query(Node).all():
    session.delete(node)
```

which is much less efficient than a bulk deletion. To improve runtime speed, it is necessary to configure foreign keys correctly on the DBMS level.